# After form submission showing 500 internal server error

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony, when i submit enquiry form showing following error in symfony2.

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> > The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

Comment: normally when see 500 internal server error, I will check the server running log to see what cause the error..

Comment: I seems like you're working on production environment (app.php entry point). If so, try dev environment (app_dev.php) in order to get more details about the problem.

Comment: tail -f `app/logs/dev.log` and then try resubmitting. The error should show in your `Terminal`...